# For mysql, do indexes help for non-unique columns?

Tags: mysql

Example table:

```
kitchen_option_id (int and primary key)
kitchen_id (int)
kitchen_chair_id (int)
```

I want to get all the chairs associated with kitchen 33.  Can I make this faster with an index?  Even though I can't make kitchen_chair_id unique?

Comment: Likely yes, but it depends on the variances of kitchen_chair ID and the volume of records that are kitchen 33.  if you have tens of thousands of records for kitchen 33 and a few a are chairs yes. If you only have a few dozen records that are kitchen 33 and all of them are chairs then not likely.  The more records which can be eliminated by the index, the greater the benefit of the index vs table scan.  Imagine a table with millions of records with Column Priority of (NULL, 1,2,3,4,5)  Indexing the column will help if you want to find a specific priority or group of priorities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put a non-unique index on `kitchen_id`. This allows the dbms to do what's known as an "index-range" scan, which is to say that the dbms does a direct index lookup for the first `kitchen_id = 33`, and then, because index keys are already sorted, it can read index keys sequentially until it finds one where `kitchen_id != 33` and then stop.

How much faster this is than a full table scan depends on the ratio `(kitchen 33) / (all kitchens)`, and the break-even point comes somehere above 1/2.

Comment: To clarify...if the number of results for kitchen 33 (say 3 chairs) is less than half the total number of options (say 200) then this would not help?

Comment: If it's ***more*** than 1/2, it ***might*** not help. If it's ***much more*** than 1/2, it won't help. It helps by eliminating records that are *not* kitchen 33; the more records eliminated, the greater the speedup. The tradeoff is that a single indexed-record read takes more IO than a single non-indexed record read.

Comment: @user2662680 for 3 entries with same `kitchen_id` amongst hundreds of entries in total, it is reasonable to use non-unique index (although 200 entries is still a small table and the DB might still decide it's faster to do a full scan).

Comment: You got it. I confess I'm not actually sure how MySQL's optimizer would decide, as the docs are a bit vague (on this and many other subjects) but both MyISAM and InnoDB appear to provide statistical cost-based optimizers that are capable of choosing the method appropriate to each individual query.